# Segmentation Error in Matrix Multiplication

Tags: c

My task is to multiply 2 Matrix using Function, Pointer and Arrays. Segmentation Error appears and debugger shows exit value -1. However, no errors and warnings in a console. Please help!

```
int main(void) {
    int matrix1[3][3] = {{1,2,3}, {4,5,6}, {7,8,9}};
    int matrix2[3][3] = {{9,8,7}, {6,5,4}, {3,2,1}};
    int rowm1 = sizeof(matrix1)/sizeof(matrix1[0]);
    int colm1 = sizeof(matrix1[0])/sizeof(matrix1[0][0]);
    int rowm2 = sizeof(matrix2)/sizeof(matrix2[0]);
    int colm2 = sizeof(matrix2[0])/sizeof(matrix2[0][0]);
    int result[rowm1][colm2];
    matmul(&matrix1, &matrix2, rowm1, rowm2, colm1, colm2, &result);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
void matmul(int **matrix1, int **matrix2, int rowm1, int rowm2, int colm1, int colm2, int **result) {
    int i,j,k,sum;
    for (i=0; i<rowm1; i++){
         for(j=0;j<colm2;j++){
             sum=0;
            for(k=0; k<colm1; k++) {
                           //Hear comes a Segmentation Error
                    printf("%d   %d \n", matrix1[0][0], matrix2[0][0]);
                    sum += matrix1[i][k] * matrix2[k][j];
                    result [i][j] = sum;
                    printf("%d\n", sum);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You have an argument type mismatch which your compiler should have reported.  You cannot pass an `int [3][3]` to an `int **`.  Declare the arguments as `int (*)[3]` instead.  And don't apply the address-of operator when passing them.

Comment: "No warnings"? I get 3 warnings.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Yes, I was just looking at the first two arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things you need to change in your code.

Change the function call to the line below.

```
matmul(rowm1, rowm2, colm1, colm2, matrix1, matrix2, result);
```

And you need to change your function parameters also like this

```
void matmul(int rowm1, int rowm2, int colm1, int colm2, int matrix1[rowm1][colm1], int matrix2[rowm2][colm2],  int result[rowm1][colm2]) {
```

While receiving you will need to provide the sizes of the matrices in `C`. Reasons why people prefer java.

And also change the printing style of your matrices and indent them well.

Before using `EXIT_SUCCESS` you will need to declare it. It isn't a defined constant.

Comment: Only needs to provide the 2nd dimension, can leave the 1st dimension blank.

Comment: Yes @AustinStephens, Since the poster is new with `c` I thought it would be better to give him more idea in the prototype.